# re.findall to search for variables starting with pattern

Tags: regex

Opening a file and trying to count the total number of occurrences of variable in it.

```
ATTRS = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
with open('_file_name', 'r') as fh:
    contents = fh.read():
    for attr in ATTRS:
        count = len(re.findall(attr, contents))
        print count
```

The code seems to be working fine to check anywhere in the file for a matching string. However, I want to search the number of occurrences only in the start of the line.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the file and what you expect to get and what you are currently getting? Also, tag it with the language, it seems like python.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. Its a simple code in python3.

```
def counter(attrs):
    with open('dummy.txt', 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read()
        for attr in attrs:
            count = 0
            rp = re.compile('^\s*' + attr + '\\b')
            for r in contents.split('\n'):
                matches = rp.match(r)
                if matches != None:
                    count += 1
            print(count)
```

Consider a dummy file like this one:

```
hello 67989 hello
hello 67989 hello hello 67989 hello
    hello 67989 hello
    hello 67989 hello
pssss hello
```

Testing the code for `attrs = ['s', 'hello', 'pssss']`:

```
In [12]: attrs = ['s', 'hello', 'pssss']
In [13]: counter(attrs)
       0
       4
       1
```

This code considers the first line of words of the line including indentation. Remove the `\s*` from the regex, if you want it strictly to be at the beginning of the line.

Explanation:

```
^    -> Start of string
\s*  -> 0 or more space like characters (including tabs)
attr -> Dynmaic attribute like `hello`
\\b  -> Word boundary to make sure when you search `hello`, `hellohello` doesn't match
```